# C++ DirectX11: NullPtr error using DirectX tool kit

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am trying to implement a font class for my game and I keep getting the following error at run time

> Exception thrown: write access violation. this was nullptr.

inside my init function in Font.cpp

```
void Font::Init(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
{
    if (device != NULL && deviceContext != NULL)
    {
        m_spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(deviceContext);//<----This line
        m_spriteFont = new SpriteFont(device, L"Fonts/Arial.spritefont");
    }
}
```

Here is my Font.h

```
#ifndef FONT_H
#define FONT_H


#include <d3d11.h>
#include <directxmath.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
#include "SpriteFont.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace DirectX;

class Font
{

public:
    Font();
    ~Font();
    void Init(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext);
    void Render();

private:
    SpriteFont* m_spriteFont;
    SpriteBatch* m_spriteBatch;
};

#endif
```

Here is my Font.cpp

```
#include "Font.h"
#include "SimpleMath.h"

Font::Font()
{
    m_spriteFont = NULL;
    m_spriteBatch = NULL;
}


Font::~Font()
{
    if (m_spriteFont)
    {
        delete m_spriteFont;
        m_spriteFont = NULL;

    }
    if (m_spriteBatch)
    {
        delete m_spriteBatch;
        m_spriteBatch = NULL;

    }
}
void Font::Init(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
{
    if (device != NULL && deviceContext != NULL)
    {
        m_spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(deviceContext);
        m_spriteFont = new SpriteFont(device, L"Fonts/Arial.spritefont");
    }
}
void Font::Render()
{
    m_spriteBatch->Begin();
    m_spriteFont->DrawString(m_spriteBatch, L"TEST", SimpleMath::Vector2(300, 300));
    m_spriteBatch->End();
}
```

and here is my GameScene.cpp

```
#include "GameScene.h"
#include "TextureShader.h"


GameScene::GameScene(void)
{
    prevtime = 0;
    collision = false;
    Sprite_Box_Height = 0;
    Sprite_Box_Width = 0;
}


GameScene::~GameScene(void)
{
    if(m_player)
    {
        delete m_player;
    }

    if (m_enemy)
    {
        delete m_enemy;
    }

    if (m_ball)
    {
        delete m_ball;
    }
    if (m_timer)
    {
        delete m_timer;
    }
}

bool GameScene::Initialize()
{
    TextureShader* shader = (TextureShader*)ResourceManager::GetInstance()->GetShaderByName("texture.fx");
    if(shader == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //create objects for all entities and initialize them
    m_ball = new Ball();
    m_ball->Initialize(Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDevice(), Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDeviceContext(), shader);
    m_player = new Player();
    m_player->Initialize(Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDevice(), Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDeviceContext(), shader);
    m_enemy = new Enemy();
    m_enemy->Initialize(Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDevice(), Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDeviceContext(), shader);
    m_font->Init(Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDevice(), Engine::GetEngine()->GetGraphics()->GetDeviceContext());

    return true;
}

void GameScene::Update()
{
    //Updade all Entities collision
    m_player->Update();
    m_enemy->Update();
    m_ball->Update();
    Collision();
}

void GameScene::Render(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, XMFLOAT4X4 viewMatrix, XMFLOAT4X4 projectionMatrix)
{
    m_font->Render();
}
void GameScene::Collision()
{
    //Get the current position of the ball and the player
    BallPos = m_ball->GetBallPosition();
    PlayerPos = m_player->GetPlayerPosition();
    EnemyPos = m_enemy->GetPlayerPosition();
    BallVel = m_ball->GetBallVelocity();
    ballVelX = BallVel.m128_f32[0];
    ballVelY = BallVel.m128_f32[1];


    //Set the size of the sprite
    Sprite_Box_Height = 50;
    Sprite_Box_Width = 20;

    //if there is a collision between the ball and a paddle get the current time
    //and reverse the ball's velocity.
    if (m_collision)
    {
        float currentTime = m_timer->GetTime();
        //Wait for the ball to exit the area before setting collison back to false
        //to prevent the ball from getting stuck
        if (prevtime > currentTime - 100)
        {
            m_collision = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_collision = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //#################################################################//
        //set collision to true when the ball is in the area of the Paddle //
        //check if ball is in the player's x vecinity                      //
        //#################################################################//

        //check if ball has near the same position player's paddle
        if (BallPos.m128_f32[0] < PlayerPos.m128_f32[0] + Sprite_Box_Width && BallPos.m128_f32[0] > PlayerPos.m128_f32[0] - Sprite_Box_Width)
        {
            //check if ball hits the top of the player's paddle
            if (BallPos.m128_f32[1] < PlayerPos.m128_f32[1] + Sprite_Box_Height && BallPos.m128_f32[1] > PlayerPos.m128_f32[1] - Sprite_Box_Height)
            {
                prevtime = m_timer->GetTime();
                m_ball->SetBallVelocity(-ballVelX, ballVelY);
                m_collision = true;
            }
        }
        else if (BallPos.m128_f32[0] < PlayerPos.m128_f32[0] + Sprite_Box_Width && BallPos.m128_f32[0] > PlayerPos.m128_f32[0] - Sprite_Box_Width)
        {
            //check if ball is in the player's y vecinity
            if (BallPos.m128_f32[1] < PlayerPos.m128_f32[1] + Sprite_Box_Height && BallPos.m128_f32[1] > PlayerPos.m128_f32[1] - Sprite_Box_Height)
            {
                prevtime = m_timer->GetTime();
                m_ball->SetBallVelocity(-ballVelX, ballVelY);
                m_collision = true;
            }
        }

        else if (BallPos.m128_f32[0] < EnemyPos.m128_f32[0] + Sprite_Box_Width && BallPos.m128_f32[0] > EnemyPos.m128_f32[0] - Sprite_Box_Width)
        {
            //check if ball is in the player's y vecinity
            if (BallPos.m128_f32[1] < EnemyPos.m128_f32[1] + Sprite_Box_Height && BallPos.m128_f32[1] > EnemyPos.m128_f32[1] - Sprite_Box_Height)
            {
                prevtime = m_timer->GetTime();
                m_ball->SetBallVelocity(-ballVelX, ballVelY);
                m_collision = true;
            }
        }
        //###################################################################//
        //set collision to true when the ball hits the edge of the screen    //
        //by checking if ball's position is passed the edge and sets it back //
        //to  a position just inside the screen                              //
        //###################################################################//
        //if the ball hits the TOP edge of the screen change ball's velocity
        if (BallPos.m128_f32[1] > 300.0f)
        {
            prevtime = m_timer->GetTime();
            m_ball->SetBallVelocity(ballVelX, -ballVelY);
            m_collision = true;
        }
        //if the ball hits the BOTTOM edge of the screen change ball's velocity
        else if (BallPos.m128_f32[1] < -300.0f)
        {
            prevtime = m_timer->GetTime();
            m_ball->SetBallVelocity(ballVelX, -ballVelY);
            m_collision = true;
        }
        //if the ball hits the RIGHT edge of the screen change ball's velocity
        else if (BallPos.m128_f32[0] > 400.0f)
        {
            prevtime = m_timer->GetTime();
            m_ball->SetBallVelocity(-ballVelX, ballVelY);
            m_collision = true;
        }
        //if the ball hits the LEFT edge of the screen change ball's velocity
        else if (BallPos.m128_f32[0] < -400.0f)
        {
            prevtime = m_timer->GetTime();
            m_ball->SetBallVelocity(-ballVelX, ballVelY);
            m_collision = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for Your help in advance!!!

Comment: It looks like you never initialize `m_font` to point to something. Debuggers are great for solving problems like this.

Comment: And your destructors contain a lot of useless code. There's no reason to check for null before calling delete and there's no reason to set the pointer values to null after calling delete (the object is no longer valid afterwards anyway).

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that in the DirectX Tool Kit [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) I recommend making use of `std::unique_ptr` rather than raw pointers is that it really simplifies the code.

```
// Font.h

#pragma once

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <directxmath.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
#include "SpriteFont.h"

class Font
{

public:
    Font() {}
    void Init(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext);
    void Render();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteFont> m_spriteFont;
    std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch> m_spriteBatch;
};

// Font.cpp
#include "Font.h"
#include "SimpleMath.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace DirectX;

void Font::Init(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
{
    if (device != NULL && deviceContext != NULL)
    {
        m_spriteBatch = std::make_unique<SpriteBatch>(deviceContext);
        m_spriteFont = std::make_unique<SpriteFont>(device, L"Fonts/Arial.spritefont");
    }
}

void Font::Render()
{
    m_spriteBatch->Begin();
    m_spriteFont->DrawString(m_spriteBatch.get(), L"TEST", SimpleMath::Vector2(300, 300));
    m_spriteBatch->End();
}
```

> You should avoid having `using namespace` statements in .h files as it basically defeats the whole purpose of using C++ namespaces in the first place. You should put `using namespace` statements only in .cpp files, and then use fully qualified names in headers.

There's no obvious reason from your posted code as to why you are getting an exception. I suggest you step into the code to see where the exception is really coming from. If you are using NuGet, then you might want to use the project-to-project reference instead. See the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK) wiki for details.

You might try using `Fonts\\Arial.spritefont` rather than `Fonts/Arial.spritefont` to see if that makes a difference.

> With modern compilers, the old-school C-style if `#ifndef FONT_H #define FONT_H .. #endif` is not necessarily. Just use `#pragma once`.

**Note:** If you are using VS 2012 rather than VS 2013 or VS 2015, then you can't make use of `std::make_unique`. You'd do the following instead:

```
m_spriteBatch.reset( new SpriteBatch(deviceContext) );
m_spriteFont.reset( new SpriteFont(device, L"Fonts/Arial.spritefont") );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was very helpful and informative!